# How to set UITableViewController custom class programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

This is my storyboard:

[image]

The UITableViewController, has a generic UITableCell (MMSwitchTableCell) that has an image, a label and switch.

The idea is to be able to create different UITableViewControllers that present different data with the same layout i.e with the same cell object and same behavior. for example one time the UITableView has a list of cells that helps you select fruits, second UITable helps you select furniture.
The two UITablesViewController have no relation between them (no inheritance or aggregation), they are different instances in different viewControllers, I only want to re-use the designed control and the UITableCell code.

So my code has a UIViewController where I declare a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MMGoSeePopoverTableViewController* goSeePopoverTableViewController;
```

and lazy load it:

```
-(MMGoSeePopoverTableViewController*) goSeePopoverTableViewController
{
    if(_goSeePopoverTableViewController == nil)
    {
        _goSeePopoverTableViewController =(MMGoSeePopoverTableViewController*)
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"switchPopover"];
    }

    return _goSeePopoverTableViewController;
}
```

and a second UIViewController in which I declare a property:

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) MMLayersPopoverTableViewController* layersPopoverTableViewController;
```

and lazy load it:

```
-(MMLayersPopoverTableViewController*) layersPopoverTableViewController
{
    if(_layersPopoverTableViewController == nil)
    {
        _layersPopoverTableViewController =(MMLayersPopoverTableViewController*)
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"switchPopover"];
    }

    return _layersPopoverTableViewController;
}
```

In the storyboard I've set the custom class to MMLayersPopoverTableViewController, instead I wish to leave it blank and somehow set it in the code. I guess I should do this inside the lazy loaders, but I can't figure how.

### Edit

The suggested "This question may already have an answer here:" is not the same as what I'm asking. I have amended the post to explain my problem better.

Comment: What's your purpose of this requirement? One View should bind to one ViewController.

Comment: @0x7fffffff thank you for the link, unfortunately you didn't understand what i'm asking so i edited the question, hopefully now its clear and you'll be able to help

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is to be able to create different UITableViewControllers that
>   present different data with the same layout i.e with the same cell
>   object & same behavior.

This sounds like a case where you should use a .xib file instead of a storyboard. The advantage of storyboards compared to .xib files is that you can see the structure of the app in terms of views and the corresponding view controllers. In your case, though, you're trying to *reuse* the same view with different view controllers. Putting your table in a .xib file that's owned by the view controller will let you load the same table, cell, etc. with whatever view controller you decide to instantiate.

In your .xib file, set the type of the File's Owner proxy to some common superclass of all your view controller classes which contains all the necessary functionality. For example, if all your view controllers are derived from `UITableViewController` and you don't need any special outlets, set the type to `UITableViewController` and connect the table to the proxy's `tableView` outlet. If your view controllers have other common behavior, put all that in a subclass of `UITableViewController`, use that as the proxy's type, and derive the other view controllers from that class.

Once you've done all that, you can use the `-initWithNibName:bundle:` method to initialize any of your view controllers and load the same view:

```
// in one place...
MMGoSeePopoverTableViewController *goSeeVC = [[MMGoSeePopoverTableViewController alloc]
                                              initWithNibName:@"CommonTableView.xib" bundle:nil"];
// and in some other place...
MMLayersPopoverTableViewController *layersVC = [[MMLayersPopoverTableViewController alloc]
                                              initWithNibName:@"CommonTableView.xib" bundle:nil"];
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to connect the table to the proxy's tableView outlet? can you place some code for that? thanks!

Comment: Just control-drag from the table to Files Owner icon in IB the same way you'd connect any other outlet.